# Toggle background color of divs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm mapping a div so it would render according to the amount of data i have in my database. In my case my div render 4 times. (This is a poll which has 4 options.)

I will explain my question in steps.

1) I want to set background color for the div which matches the id i'm getting 
from the database when the page loads. I did it like this

```
    componentDidMount() {

            let sel3 = document.getElementById(this.props.voted_id);

            if (sel3) {

                sel3.style.backgroundColor = "#0b97c4";
                sel3.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
            }
        }
```

here `this.props.voted_id` is the id i'm getting from the database. (It is the id of the poll option user has selected. So on componentDidMount i'm displaying the selected option by setting a background color to it)

2) If the user wants to change his/her choice user can change it by clicking on the new choice. I want to set background color to the new choice user selected and in the same time i want to remove the background color of the previously selected choice.
I'm doing it like this

**my component**

```
render() {

        let {contents, submitvote, postId, voted_id} = this.props

        return (

            <div className="txt_vote_bar_div" id={this.props.contents.post_poll_content_id}>
                <p className="txt_vote_choice" id={this.props.contents.post_poll_content_id}
                   onClick={() => {
                       this.handleClick(this.props.contents.post_poll_content_id);
                   }}>
                    {contents.content}
                </p>
                <p className="txt_tot_votes"> {this.props.contents.votes_percentage}%
                    ({this.state.voteCount} Votes)</p>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

On handleClick function i'm doing the following

```
 handleClick(id) {

        let sel = document.getElementById(this.props.voted_id);
    if (sel) {
        alert("1");
        sel.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        sel.style.color = "#6a6a6a";
    }

    let sel2 = document.getElementById(this.props.getVoteStatus);
    if (sel2) {
        alert("2");
        sel2.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        sel2.style.color = "#6a6a6a";
    }

    let el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (el) {
        alert("3");
        this.setState({

            active: false,

        })
        el.style.backgroundColor = "#0b97c4";
        el.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
    }



    let sel3 = document.getElementById(id);
    if (sel3.id == this.props.getVoteStatus && this.state.active == false) {
        alert("4");
        this.setState({
            active: true,
        })
        sel3.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        sel3.style.color = "#6a6a6a";
    }

    }
```

here `this.props.voted_id` is the id of choice i'm getting from the database (i use this id to set a background on `componentDidMount`)

here `this.props.getVoteStatus` is the previously selected id of the choice which i'm using to remove the background color when user selects a new choice.

Upto this point i'm doing this successfully with no issues. But my problem is this

When the page loades and if i get a id from the database , that particular div with the id is colored.That is ok. But when user selects the same choice (to retract his/her choice)

this piece of code runs as it should (Because the user selected div id is same as the id i'm getting from the database)

```
let sel = document.getElementById(this.props.voted_id);
        if (sel) {
            alert("2");
            sel.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
            sel.style.color = "#6a6a6a";
        }
```

and after that this piece of code runs

```
let el = document.getElementById(id);
        if (el) {
            alert("1");
            this.setState({
                active: false,
            })
            el.style.backgroundColor = "#0b97c4";
            el.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
        }
```

This problem comes only one time after the page loads. In that instance both part of codes are valid. Therefore it runs the both. How can i fix this problem?

**UPDATE**

This is how i'm mapping my div element

```
export const TextVoteList = ({postData, submitvote}) => {

    const dataUnavailable = (
        <div>
            <p>
                There are no voting options available available
            </p>
        </div>
    );

    const dataAvailable = (
        <div>
            {postData.post_poll_content.map(contents => <TextVoteOptions key={contents.post_poll_content_id} voted_id={postData.personal_vote}  contents={contents} submitvote = {submitvote} postId = {postData._id}/>)}
        </div>
    );

    return (

        <div>
            {postData.post_poll_content.length === 0 ? dataUnavailable : dataAvailable}
        </div>

    );
};
```

**TextVoteOptions** code

```
render() {

        alert(this.props.getVoteResponse);

        let {contents, submitvote, postId, voted_id} = this.props

        return (


            <div key={this.props.contents.post_poll_content_id} className= {(this.state.voted_id === this.props.contents.post_poll_content_id && this.state.active)  ? "txt_vote_bar_div active" :  "txt_vote_bar_div"}>
                <p className="txt_vote_choice" id={this.props.contents.post_poll_content_id}
                   onClick={() => {
                       this.handleClick(this.props.contents.post_poll_content_id);
                   }}>
                    {contents.content}
                </p>
                <p className="txt_tot_votes"> {this.props.contents.votes_percentage}%
                    ({this.state.voteCount} Votes)</p>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

**my click handler**

```
handleClick(id) {

        let vote_object = {
            voting_object: id,
            post_id: this.props.postId
        }

        this.setState({
            voted_id: id,
            active: (id != this.state.voted_id) ? true : !this.state.active
        });


        this.props.submitvote(vote_object);

    }
```

Comment: Cant you put condition like this `if(el.style.backgroundColor === "#0b97c4"){ el.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"} else{el.style.backgroundColor = "#0b97c4"}`

Comment: i tried this but i cannot get it to work. it does not go inside if(el.style.backgroundColor === "#0b97c4"){ }

Comment: I think, i am confused with your question. So correct me if wrong, so in a simple way, you have multiple divs, which you are rendering based on 'contents' which i am assuming is an array. You are displaying some colorA on divs  based on 'this.props.contents.post_poll_content_id' and color B for the div based on "this.props.voted_id". Now you want to toggle the colors(i.e colorA or colorB) , deciding new vote. Am I right?

Comment: Try checking if( id == this.props.voted_id) {return} so if user clicked same div again, just return from handleclick

Comment: @Dev yeah u are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should avoid actual DOM manipulations on your own. Let React take care of actual DOM manipulation. As per my understanding, I have designed as below. Please try and relate. Hope this helps.

In your question, I didn't understand the usage of state 'active', So i have not used in the below snippet. Is this what you are trying to acheive.

```js
const contents = [
  {
    post_poll_content_id: 1,
    content: "Soccer",
    votes_percentage: 60
  },
  {
    post_poll_content_id: 2,
    content: "Cricket",
    votes_percentage: 20
  },
  {
    post_poll_content_id: 3,
    content: "Basketball",
    votes_percentage: 20
  }
];

const votedId = 3; // Assume this is coming from database;

class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      voteCount: 100,
      voted_id: props.voted_id,
      active:true
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(id) {
    this.setState({
        voted_id: id,
        active: (id != this.state.voted_id) ? true : !this.state.active
    });
    
  }

  render() {
   let {contents, voted_id} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {contents.map((content, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index} className= {(this.state.voted_id===content.post_poll_content_id && this.state.active)  ? "txt_vote_bar_div active" :  "txt_vote_bar_div"}
                 id={content.post_poll_content_id}
            >
              <p
                className="txt_vote_choice"
                id={content.post_poll_content_id}
                onClick={() => {
                  this.handleClick(content.post_poll_content_id);
                }}
              >
                {content.content}
              </p>
              <p className="txt_tot_votes">
                {content.votes_percentage % this.state.voteCount} Votes
              </p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Demo contents={contents} voted_id = {votedId}/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
.txt_vote_bar_div {
   display:block;
   border:1px solid #eee;
   margin: 10px;
   width:20%;
   text-align:center;
}

.active {
  background-color:#0b97c4;
  color:#FFF;
}

.txt_vote_choice {
   color:'blue';
   cursor:pointer;
   text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I want to remove the background color if the user clicks on the same div as well. How is it possible in your approach?

Comment: @CraZyDroiD Ohh in that case you may need 'active' in state to toggle. I have updated the snippet. Please have a look.

Comment: One more issue. Click on one of the div.Then click again the same div to remove the color. Then click on a new div. You have to click twice to set a background color to it. It seems like that state is set after the first click. You can try it in your example.

Comment: @CraZyDroiD, Ohh yes. I have updated the handleClick handler in the answer. Check now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Using your help i'm setting background color for the selected div. But i'm mapping this different to  your way. I have updated my code in my question.Please take a look. The problem i'm facing is even though i'm setting the background color to the selected div, previously selected div does not remove the background color. I think it's because i'm not using 'index' value as in your answer.

Comment: Can you add your updated click handler also. I don't see any problem. 'index' is the second param of map() which states the  current element being processed in the array. You can use that as well in your case. But i don't think that might be the problem.

Comment: @CraZyDroiD: I don't see any problem. Truly speaking its difficult to identify without actual code/debugging. It will be helpful if you create some plunker.

Comment: the problem was with the mapping. I mapped the component as you have done and now it's working perfectly. Thanks alot!