# Poweroff toggle button/div

Tags: javascript, css

I’m trying to make a power off button (actually it is a `div`), that when I click, it will change its appearance.
It looks like an interruptor, so I want to change the `background-color` of the page, the color of the icon ‘power off’ and the `border-style` of the button.

I took this function from another site and it is doing well in adding once a CSS property, but I want it to go on and of always.

```
document.getElementById('io').addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (this.classList.contains('poweroff')) {
  //  this.classList.remove('poweroff');
   this.classList.add('on');
  } else {
     this.classList.remove('on');
  }
});
```

I believe the logic will be something like

```
x = x - 1
```

where `x` need to go turning from `0` to `1` and from `1` to `0`, every time I click the button.

```
<body>
<div class="interruptor">
<div id="io" class="poweroff">
<i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
</div>
</div>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ddde7c70b6.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/logic.js" charset="utf-8"> </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML and CSS also

Comment: Put that in your question, please, not as a comment.

Comment: Why aren't you using a proper `<button>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle background color of divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45769850/toggle-background-color-of-divs)

Comment: @Rob because I needed to style like an outlet/interruptor, and I found it easier.

Comment: Styling a button is no different than styling a div except a button has some built in styles. However, `<button>` is semantically correct for this while `<div>` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are checking on the basis of `powerOff` class you need to toggle it also like this

```
document.getElementById('io').addEventListener('click', function () {
if (this.classList.contains('poweroff')) {
  this.classList.remove('poweroff');
  this.classList.add('on');
} else {
  this.classList.add('poweroff');
  this.classList.remove('on');
}
});
```

Instead of checking `if` condition and adding and removing classes, use toggle like this

[Read Here about toggle](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp)

```
document.getElementById('io').addEventListener('click', function () {
 this.classList.toggle('on');
});
```

Comment: Toggle accomplish perfectly my goal!

Answer (score 0):

You should use toggle instead of add and remove, as :

```
 document.getElementById('io').addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (this.classList.contains('poweroff')) {
     this.classList.toggle('poweroff');
     this.classList.toggle('on');
  } else {
    this.classList.toggle('on');
  }
});
```

This way it will automatically add and remove class on button click.